# Create two vectors in the same row

Tags: math-mode, vector

I have two vectors y and b one over the other. I wish to have the two vectors on the some row, in order to save pages in my document.

```
        \begin{align*}
            y = \begin{pmatrix}
                a_{0}\\ 
                a_{1}\\ 
                a_{2}\\ 
                \vdots \\ 
                a_{p}\\
                c_{1}\\
                c_{2}\\
                \vdots \\
                c_{m}\\
                \end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{(m+p+1)}
    \end{align*}

    \begin{align*}
            b = \begin{pmatrix}
                f_{0}\\ 
                f_{1}\\ 
                f_{2}\\ 
                \vdots \\ 
                f_{n}\\
                \end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{(n+1)}
    \end{align*}
```

[image]

Comment: What is the `equ` environment?

Comment: I found in an Overleaf example, but I removed.

Comment: You are using two `align*` environments, creating two separate display maths. If you put both vectors in one `align*` they will be next to each other. or am I understanding the question wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}


\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
            \mathbf{y} = \begin{pmatrix}
                a_{0}\\ 
                a_{1}\\ 
                a_{2}\\ 
                \vdots \\ 
                a_{p}\\
                c_{1}\\
                c_{2}\\
                \vdots \\
                c_{m}\\
                \end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{(m+p+1)}, \qquad 
            \mathbf{b} = \begin{pmatrix}
                f_{0}\\ 
                f_{1}\\ 
                f_{2}\\ 
                \vdots \\ 
                f_{n}\\
                \end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{(n+1)}
    \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why `align*`?  It seems that `gather*` be more adequate. Or even simpler `\[ ... \]`. Anyway +1 ;-)

Comment: @Zarko Neither `gather*` is adequate: `equation*` is the right one (which is the same as `\[...\]`, by the way).

Comment: @egreg, I know that `equation*` is the same as `\[ ... \] ` :-). Regarding `gather`: it differ from `equation` in two ways: most obvious is that it handle multiline equations and maybe less know that it handle vertical spaces above equation less sophisticated than `equation` (if I remember correctly. Of course, you know this (better than me)  ;-)

Comment: @Zarko Hi, I had only taken the snippet code of the user :-(..I'm sorry.

Comment: @egreg Thank you very much for the edit to my answer. Best regards.

Answer (score 4):

You should use a single `equation*` environment (use `align` *only* when an alignment is concerned), as already suggested.

There are other space saving options, though.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}


\begin{equation*}
  y =
  \begin{pmatrix}
  a_{0}\\ 
  a_{1}\\ 
  a_{2}\\ 
  \vdots \\ 
  a_{p}\\
  c_{1}\\
  c_{2}\\
  \vdots \\
  c_{m}
  \end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{(m+p+1)}
\quad\text{and}\quad
  b =
  \begin{pmatrix}
  f_{0}\\ 
  f_{1}\\ 
  f_{2}\\ 
  \vdots \\ 
  f_{n}\\
  \end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{(n+1)}
\end{equation*}
But, if you really want to save space, you can use an alignment
\begin{align*}
  y &=
  \begin{pmatrix}
  a_{0} & 
  a_{1} & 
  a_{2} & 
  \cdots & 
  a_{p} &
  c_{1} &
  c_{2} &
  \cdots &
  c_{m}
  \end{pmatrix}^{T} \in \mathbb{R}^{(m+p+1)}
\\
  b &=
  \begin{pmatrix}
  f_{0} & 
  f_{1} & 
  f_{2} & 
  \cdots & 
  f_{n} 
  \end{pmatrix}^T \in \mathbb{R}^{(n+1)}
\end{align*}
or center both vectors
\begin{gather*}
  y =
  \begin{pmatrix}
  a_{0} & 
  a_{1} & 
  a_{2} & 
  \cdots & 
  a_{p} &
  c_{1} &
  c_{2} &
  \cdots &
  c_{m}
  \end{pmatrix}^{T} \in \mathbb{R}^{(m+p+1)}
\\
  b =
  \begin{pmatrix}
  f_{0} & 
  f_{1} & 
  f_{2} & 
  \cdots & 
  f_{n} 
  \end{pmatrix}^T \in \mathbb{R}^{(n+1)}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]